# How I can verify that an incoming http body is multipart/form-data using regex and nodejs?

Tags: node.js, regex, http

At my nodejs project, I want to validate if an incoming http request is just a valid multipart/form-data one.

So far I tried the following example:

```
const http = require('http');

const validateMultipartFormData = (body) => {
   // Somehow use a logic to verify whether body is a multipart one.
   // For now I return a dummy logic
   return true;
};
  
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

  var body = [];

    req.on('data', (data) => body.push(data));

    req.on('end', () => {
      body = body.toString();

      const validMultipart =  validateMultipartFormData(body);

      if (req.headers['content-type'].includes('multipart/form-data')) {

        const statuscode = validMultipart?200:400;
        const validStatusMsg = validMultipart?"Valid Body":"Invalid Multipart";
        
        res.statusCode=statuscode;
        res.end(validStatusMsg);

      } else {
        res.end("No Multipart Body")
      }
    });
});

server.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on http://localhost:8080/ ...');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the desired regex is:

```
/[\-\w]+\r\nContent-Disposition:\sform-data;\sname=.*\r\n/
```

Therefore, the function `validateMultipartFormData` will be:

```
const validateMultipartFormData = (body) => {
    const pattern = /[\-\w]+\r\nContent-Disposition:\sform-data;\sname=.*\r\n/;
    return pattern.test(body);
};
```

A working example is:

```
const http = require('http');


const validateMultipartFormData = (body) => {
    const pattern = /[\-\w]+\r\nContent-Disposition:\sform-data;\sname=.*\r\n/;
    return pattern.test(body);
};
  

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

  var body = [];

    req.on('data', (data) => body.push(data));

    req.on('end', () => {
      body = body.toString();

      const validMultipart =  validateMultipartFormData(body);

      if (req.headers['content-type'].includes('multipart/form-data')) {

        const statuscode = validMultipart?200:400;
        const validStatusMsg = validMultipart?"Valid Body":"Invalid Multipart";
        
        res.statusCode=statuscode;
        res.end(validStatusMsg);

      } else {
        res.end("No Multipart Body")
      }
    });
});

server.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on http://localhost:8080/ ...');
});
```

---

### Philosophy Behind the regex

Multipart http bodies are fields seperated with seperator strings terminated by `\r\n`. Usually at most cases the seperator looks like this:

```
--------------------------e2953aef605ceeb2
```

The `\r\n` are not printable chars therefore not shown in string above. If we escape them the seperator string will be:

```
--------------------------e2953aef605ceeb2\r\n
```

Each separator string is defined upon http header `Content-Type`. For the above seperator the header will have the value:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------e2953aef605ceeb2
```

The separator string is defined at `; boundary` section of the header. By testing the boundary will start with some dashes (`-`) and will terminate with some random characters and `\r\n` (`\r` indicate the character return carriage whilst `\n` indicate the character newline).

Also the body will always contain as well:

```
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name=
```

Then some other characters will follow and will always terminate with `\r\n`.

Therefore, if I try to check whether these 2 lines exist, I can be sure most of the cases the content will match `miltipart/form-data` header.